# make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.9.24-v7+/build: No such file or directory. Stop

Tags: raspbian, cryptsetup

I fetched cryptodev source from http://nwl.cc/pub/cryptodev-linux/cryptodev-linux-1.9.tar.gz to directory `~/cryptodev`, I unpacked tar archive and I entered into `~/cryptodev/cryptodev-linux-1.9` directory. I followed instructions on https://github.com/cryptodev-linux/cryptodev-linux/blob/master/INSTALL and I enter make command and I got below error:

```
hubot@hubot-vps:~/cryptodev/cryptodev-linux-1.9 $ make
make -C /lib/modules/4.9.24-v7+/build M=/home/hubot/cryptodev/cryptodev-linux-1.9 modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.9.24-v7+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:27: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

I stopped at this error and I do not know what should I do next. I count on help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: ls: cannot access /lib/modules/4.9.24-v7+/build: No such file or directory

Comment: @GAD3R 4.9.24+  4.9.24-v7+  4.9.28+  4.9.28-v7+

Comment: @GAD3R Linux hubot-vps 4.9.24-v7+ #993 SMP Wed Apr 26 18:01:23 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: I'm trying install cryptodev on Raspbian with enabled crypt luks.

Comment: @GAD3R linux headers not found

Comment: sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's still relevant, but I've had similar issue and ,as [Mark Plotnick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/49439/mark-plotnick) said in the comments, the following command fixed it:

```
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

Comment: This fix didn't work for me on Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 \n \l.  The build directory still doesn't exist

Comment: Have you tried creating /lib/modules/4.9.24-v7+/build manually?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around this by running

`sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.97-v7l+ build`

Note I do not know if using a different build will cause issues, but I was able to build my package after doing this.

Comment: You forgot to mention that you need to be in /lib/modules/4.19.97-v71+ folder in order to execute this command!